# Formatting in a textArea append. Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, formatting

how do you format text in a `textArea` when appending it?

```
  try{
        //establish connection to database
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "Hotel", "1234");     
        //create statement for querying database
        statement = connection.createStatement();

     //            statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TBLSTUDENT VALUES("+id+",'"+name+"','"+course+"',"+age+")");
        //query database
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Customer");

        //process query results
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        textArea.append("Hotel Database: \n");
        for(int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns; i++){

            textArea.append(metaData.getColumnName(i));//"%-8s\t",

        }
        System.out.println();

        while(resultSet.next()){
            for(int i=1; i<=numberOfColumns;i++){
                textArea.append(resultSet.getObject(i).toString());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }catch(SQLException sqlException){
        sqlException.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Right now the output is that it only appends into one line.

And it should be

Column 1-Column 2-Column 3

data1-data 2-data 3

I tried using the formatting `%-8s\t` but it doesn't work on `.append()`

Comment: "*does not work*" is not descriptive enough. What actually happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `JTextArea`'s not the best choice, you should be using a `JTable`

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

However, try using something more like `textArea.append(String.format("%-8s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i)));` instead

You will also need to `append` a new line character (`\n`) between the lines